# Why is sequential convoy pattern required in logic app?

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps, azure-servicebus-topics

I have

1. Session enabled service bus topic
2. Logic app to listen to this topic
3. Requirement to process message in order

This link explains how to implement the sequential convoy pattern when using logic apps to ensure ordered processing of the messages.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/send-related-messages-sequential-convoy

**Questions**

1. Is this implementation just a recommendation or mandatory? In either
   case, I would like to know why!
2. Instead of reading 1st message and
   then subsequent ones, why shouldn't I simply use "*when one or more
   messages arrive in topic (peek-lock)*" trigger by specifying the
   a number of messages and session id as Next Available.

Answer (score 0):

1. I'd say this is more of an example of how you can your implement the pattern using logic apps. There could be valid scenarios where certain aspects of this like the fact that all messages are processed as part of a single logic app run is required.
2. This should work just as well AFAIK. This is in fact the same trigger being used in this implementation as well.